# How can I query events from event bridge in my local nodejs application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I am using `AWS event bridge` as event bus for my applications running in AWS. Most of the services are in Lambda.

I am writing some integration test and I don't know how I can test events have been sent to event bridge. My integration tests are running in CI which is a docker container. How can I let eventbridge trigger an event to my nodejs application running in CI or local environment? If not, can I query events from event bridge? I have looked at the API reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EventBridge.html but I can't find any API I can use.

Or is there a way for me to view all events passed through event bridge?

Comment: You can have SNS trigger with http endpoint. The endpoint could be your local application if it can expose any http path to be called by sns.

Comment: I don't expose any server from my local which is unfortunate. Is there a way for me to view all events pass through eventbridge?

Comment: I'm not aware of such out-of-the box functionality. You could create a simple lambda function which would store all events in DynamoDB. Then on your local tests you could query the database.